# Opening Access data in R on a mac

Tags: osx, r, microsoft-access

I have a load of old data on a Microsoft access (accdb) file. I can't open it on my mac, is there a way to open it directly in R? Is there a package that will let me do this? I don't need to open it on my laptop anyway, just get it straight into R.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Package odbc (or the older RODBC), and a Microsoft Access Driver for MacOS will probably do the job. MS Office is available for the Mac, so there should be a database driver. (I don't know MacOS that well so this is just a comment).

Comment: @knb thanks very much! Sadly even though mac has MS Office, it is missing the Access Driver! It has everything else... very frustrating

Comment: Maybe there is a free download of the driver, somewhere on the Microsoft website. Often these are wrapped in larger packages called "SDKs"  e.g. DotnetSDK, OfiiceSDK etc. MS changes this all the time. And the driver is also sometimes called "Jet driver" (Jet is the codename of the SQL "engine")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually saving tables as excel files and importing them one by one into R.

Answer (score 0):

[REbaseData](https://www.rebasedata.com/) offer an online facility to convert the data tables from accdb files to a zip of Excel spreadsheets *which I am sure that you can open with R* - the [pricing](https://www.rebasedata.com/pricing) looks reasonable and includes 1 small file conversion for free as a trial.